# In Android, a specific image in the download folder is causing a "permission denied" error while other images in the same folder are fine

Tags: flutter, image, permissions

The specific image in the download folder is causing a permission error in an Android app built with flutter. Strangely, other images in the same folder work fine, and this issue occurs only with this particular image.

While it works fine on older Android versions, testing on Android OS version 12 revealed this problem.

When placing the image in the assets folder and using Image.asset, the rendering works correctly. Additionally, viewing the image through Android's gallery app or file explorer shows no issues, and the image displays correctly when moved to Windows desktop.

Permissions were configured in the AndroidManifest.xml file and obtained by using PermissionHandler as follows.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**dart code**

```
await Permission.storage.request();
```

The image should be rendered with below code, but it doesn't.

**dart code**

```
Image.file(''/storage/emulated/0/Download/permission_denied_image.jpg');
```

The sample project can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hYl0bwRLU0wGACO9kiEjy_pAMJM23tbM/view?usp=drive_link). The image is in 'assets' folder.

Comment: what does `print(File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/permission_denied_image.jpg').statSync())` show?

Comment: and compare it with the file you can read

Comment: both shows FileState, changed time, modified time, accessed time, mode and size without error.

Comment: mode is both "rw-rw----"
size is exact same number of file bytes length. 10200 and 79417.

Comment: Hmm.. when my coworker tried to render the image with .net WPF, he got an error message like below.

StackTrace:
   / System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.GetColorContextsHelper(GetColorContextsDelegate getColorContexts)
   / System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.get_ColorContexts()
   / System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
   / System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.OnDownloadCompleted(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: And following the advice provided in the following link resolved the issue for .net.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967535/an-interesting-exception-while-get-an-image-from-internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967535/an-interesting-exception-while-get-an-image-from-internet). But, it's not helpful for flutter.